Azure and VSTO Addin - Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=6.0.0.0,
I'm really stumped on this one. I am trying to call the Azure Form Recognizer from within a VSTO Excel add-in, uploading a local document to be analyzed and I have been getting all sorts of errors.
Here's the current error output, there's a fair bit more than what I put in the title: https://pastebin.com/niS9n0V3
I have tried using the same Azure.AI.FormRecognizer library in a regular old console app and it works fine. I have run both Excel and VS as admin. I have also been able to make a simple call to a REST API just to see if Excel was blocking internet connections or something, no problems with that.
Here's the current code:
using System;
using System.IO;


using Azure;
using Azure.AI.FormRecognizer.DocumentAnalysis;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ExcelAddIn6
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {

        static string key2 = "key";
        static string endpoint2 = "endpoint";

        static string imagepath = "path to file";

        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            //Authenticate
            AzureKeyCredential credential = new AzureKeyCredential(key2);
            DocumentAnalysisClient client = new DocumentAnalysisClient(new Uri(endpoint2), credential);

            //Send file on local disk to OCR
            LaunchOCR(client);

        }


        public void LaunchOCR(DocumentAnalysisClient c)
        {
            try
            {
                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    AnalyzeDocumentOperation operation = c.AnalyzeDocument(WaitUntil.Completed, "prebuilt-invoice", (Stream)File.Open(imagepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite));
                    AnalyzeResult result = operation.Value;
                }).Wait();
            }
            catch (AggregateException ae)
            {
                // Handle the AggregateException
                ae.Handle((x) =>
                {
                    if (x is RequestFailedException rfe)
                    {
                        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show($"Error analyzing document: {rfe.Message}");
                        return true;
                    }
                    // Handle other exceptions
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show($"An error occurred: {x.Message}");
                    return true;
                });
            }
        }


        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        #region VSTO generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }
        
        #endregion
    }
}


I'm not very strong with all these supporting .config files, so here is my packages.config just in case that has any impact:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Azure.AI.FormRecognizer" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Azure.Core" version="1.34.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Buffers" version="4.5.1" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" version="6.0.1" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.IO" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Memory" version="4.5.4" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Memory.Data" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.4" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Numerics.Vectors" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Runtime" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="6.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encodings.Web" version="4.7.2" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Text.Json" version="4.7.2" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" version="4.5.4" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.ValueTuple" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
</packages>


It is like Azure.AI.FormRecognizer package dependencies require a specific version of System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource (version 6.0.0.0), but a different version is being loaded at runtime.

The error message indicates that the assembly being loaded is version 6.0.0.0, but the one referenced in the packages.config is 4.5.1. This mismatch is causing the FileLoadException.

Here you need to add an assembly binding redirect to the app.config file to redirect the runtime to use the correct version.
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>


There is no change in the above code it works fine. By this, it can pick the file/doc/png from local and analyse through Azure Form Recognizer.


Hi, thank you for your response. However, my app.config was completely blank prior to this, I don't know if I've done something in my settings to make it not appear. But I added it in, and put in this xml but it doesn't seem to get rid of my error message? Do you know what might be going wrong?
I ran File.Exists(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile) and it returns true, so it appears to be seeing the configuration file?

If possible, please provide more info on how you setup your app.config.
